# How do I catch stack errors of all types?

Tags: c++, exception

I am trying a try-catch on this program as you see in the main, however, I can only catch errors individually, for example here I can only catch char:

```
catch (stack<char>::Empty)
```

However, I want to catch errors of all types, double,string, etc... How do I do that?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


template <class T>
class stack{
    T *s;
    int size;
    int top;
public:
    //neww
    class Full{};
    class Empty{};
    //neww
    stack(int sz)
    {
        size=sz;
        s = new T[sz];
        top=-1;
    }
    void push(T e);

    T pop()
    {

        if (top<0)
            throw Empty();

        return s[top--];
    }
};
template <class T>
void stack<T>::push(T e)
    {
        if (top>=size)
            throw Full();
        s[++top]=e;
    }
int main()
{
    stack<char> s(5);

    try {
        s.pop();
        s.push('a');
        s.push('b');
        cout<<s.pop()<<endl;
        stack<double> s1(10);
        s1.push(3.2);
        s1.push(0.5);
        cout<<s1.pop()<<endl;

    }

    catch (stack<char>::Full ) {
        cout <<"Stack is full!"<<endl;
        return 1;
    }

    catch (stack<char>::Empty) {

        cout <<"Stack is empty!"<<endl;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I can't do catch(...) since I need to handle two types of exceptions, full and empty.

Comment: You say `catch(...)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can derive your exception classes from a common, un-templated base class, and catch by reference to that:

```
struct Stack_Full { };
struct Stack_Empty { };

template <class T>
class stack{
    ...
    class Full : public Stack_Full {};
    class Empty : public Stack_Empty {};
    ...
};

...
    catch (const Stack_Full&) {
```

If you never want to catch only `stack<T>::XYZ` for some `T`/`XYZ`, you can `throw` the un-templated types directly.  You might or might not want to create a dedicated un-templated class or namespace to hold this is similar support code.

Comment: @GeorgeStop Sure - no worries.  Cheers.